# TYPO3 lib.general.logo Cannot add two images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a problem with TypoScript:

According to the website from t3sbootstrap (http://www.t3sbootstrap.de/konfiguration/snippets/) I just have to add this Code to the Template Setup to get my Logo below the NavBar:

```
lib.general.logo = IMAGE 
lib.general.logo { 
  file = fileadmin/Images/TYPO3_logo.png
  file.width = 200
  stdWrap.typolink.parameter = 1
  stdWrap.typolink.ATagParams = class="pull-left"
}
```

This works fine, but I want to add two images next to each other (same height) which link to different URLs. I tried different things, but either none or only one image is shown

I use TYPO3 7.6.16 with the Extenstion T3sbootstrap (v3.3.7)

Thanks for reading my stupid question until here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an `COA` to put two images into it:

```
lib.general.logo = COA
lib.general.logo { 
  10 = IMAGE
  10 {
    file = fileadmin/Images/TYPO3_logo.png
    file.width = 200
    stdWrap.typolink.parameter = 1
    stdWrap.typolink.ATagParams = class="pull-left"
  }

  20 < .10
  20.file = fileadmin/Images/Logo2.png
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. If i add "20.stdWrap.typolink.parameter = 2" then the second image also links to another page. Thank you very much for the help!